# Converting a 2d surface into a 3d volume

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, 3d-printing

I have a 2d surface shown in the image below using ListPlot3D[]:

[image]
It is generated with one line of code:

```
ListPlot3D[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {10,10}]]
```

Currently, it's a 'white noise' surface, meaning the surface is more or less random between zero and one. I'd like to give this thickness (so I can ultimately 3d print it).

I'd like the remaining 5 sides to be flat, so that I'd end up with a "cube" with one surface jagged.

Is there an easy way to do this? Essentially just fill in everything below the surface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This should do it:

```
ListPlot3D[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {10, 10}],
   Filling -> Axis, Boxed -> False
  ] // DiscretizeGraphics
```

Comment: +1 To make the structure sturdier, have the filling go to a negative value, e.g. `Filling -> -0.25`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `PlotTheme -> "FilledSurface"]`:

```
ListPlot3D[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {10, 10}], 
 PlotTheme -> "FilledSurface", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
DiscretizeGraphics @ %
```

[image]

You might also consider `PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface"`:

```
ListPlot3D[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {10, 10}], 
 PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1.2}]
```

[image]

```
DiscretizeGraphics @ %
```

[image]